# x11extras на MS Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Можно ли использовать x11extras из Qt в MS Windows?

Comment: Зачем? Что за проблему Вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @ixSci уже не важно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко - нет.

X11 extras это набор всяких низкоуровневых API для взимодействия с Xorg. В Windows таких API просто нет.

А насколько мне не изменяет память, то в extras только один класс [`X11Info`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qx11info.html) который предоставляет доступ к хендлу дисплея и прочей низкоуровневой кухне, которую трудно сделать в переносимой манере, но которая нужна. Например для взаимодействия с хранителем экрана и т.п.